# monitoring docker container performance using cadvisor / cgroup, best approach

Tags: docker, graphite, collectd, grafana, cadvisor

we are planning to use [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) for collecting cgroup  data from docker host. we have set up using collectd and grafana to chart monitoring of other app metrics.

1. anyone know plugins for cadvisor plugin for collectd ? as per my info collectd can not pull data of cgroup docker containers.
2. cadvisor has influxdb support, and grafana can hook up to influxdb for metrics visualization. but as we do not have influxdb in place in current landscape we are exploring quick approach for docker container metrics monitoring.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

cAdvisor plugin for collectd would be pretty simple. Can you file an issue on github.com/google/cadvisor and we can help you get one.

Alternatively, you can always hit the cAdvisor rest endpoint for the whole machine or a particular container to pull the data into graphite and push it from a helper process. eg.

/api/v1.3/containers/

In any case, file a feature request and we can help you out with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) to collect data from cadvisor using [fluent-plugin-cadvisor](https://github.com/Woorank/fluent-plugin-cadvisor).

Maybe it is not the best plugin, but it's very easy to extend and add it as you own plugin to fluentd.